# How to Check if database exists in PyMySQL

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I'm trying to check if database exists in Python. I found that it can be done using the following sql statement: `cur.execute(f'SHOW DATABASES LIKE {event["db_name"]}')` However,after trying to execute it I get the following errors:

```
[ERROR] ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TestLAU' at line 1")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/handler.py", line 63, in handler
    cur.execute(f'SHOW DATABASES LIKE {event["db_name"]}')
  File "/var/task/pymysql/cursors.py", line 170, in execute
    result = self._query(query)
  File "/var/task/pymysql/cursors.py", line 328, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  File "/var/task/pymysql/connections.py", line 517, in query
    self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
  File "/var/task/pymysql/connections.py", line 732, in _read_query_result
    result.read()
  File "/var/task/pymysql/connections.py", line 1075, in read
    first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()
  File "/var/task/pymysql/connections.py", line 684, in _read_packet
    packet.check_error()
  File "/var/task/pymysql/protocol.py", line 220, in check_error
    err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
  File "/var/task/pymysql/err.py", line 109, in raise_mysql_exception
    raise errorclass(errno, errval)
```

Answer (score 1):

You miss an apostrophe in your statement and you can use `%` in your `LIKE` statement in order to match more results, try the following:

```
cur.execute(f"SHOW DATABASES LIKE '%{event["db_name"]}%;'")
```

more about `LIKE` operator:

```
LIKE 'a%'   Finds any values that start with "a"
LIKE '%a'   Finds any values that end with "a"
LIKE '%or%' Finds any values that have "or" in any position
LIKE '_r%'  Finds any values that have "r" in the second position
LIKE 'a__%' Finds any values that start with "a" and are at least 3 characters in length
LIKE 'a%o'  Finds any values that start with "a" and ends with "o"
```

Answer (score -1):

Turns out the error was caused by the fact that I needed to surround the database name with quotes so the following SQL statement worked:  `cur.execute(f'SHOW DATABASES LIKE "{event["db_name"]}"')`

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought by apostrophe you meant `%` symbol, English is not my first language. However, I tried the code snipped and it didn't work because I needed to surround  `{event["db_name"]}` in double quotes  because otherwise it's treated as end of string.